# Unhandled Exception: HiveError: You need to initialize Hive or provide a path to store the box

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-hive

I am trying to use Hive database in my flutter app. I have followed the youtube tutorials but the code is not working in my app.
I am getting the following error.

```
Unhandled Exception: HiveError: You need to initialize Hive or provide a path to store the box.
```

**Here is my code...**

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final dbDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  await Hive.initFlutter(dbDir.path);
  Hive.registerAdapter(AddToCartAdapter());
  await Hive.openBox<AddToCart>('addToCart');
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

```
Future cartlist(String name, String unit, String qty, String price) async {
    await Hive.openBox("addToCart");
    final cart = AddToCart()
      ..name = name
      ..unit = unit
      ..qty = qty
      ..price = price;

    final Box = Boxes.getAddToCart();
    Box.add(cart)
;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also use Hive as a local database. I noticed that I din't specify subDir param and just initiated like that:

```
await Hive.initFlutter();
Hive.registerAdapter(AddToCartAdapter());
```

The problem is occurring to you, because you are using *Hive.initFlutter* with **dbDir.path** path and while using *Hive.openBox* you are not specifying that path again, You need to specify **same** path for **openBox** method.

I suggest your code should be like that:

```
Future<void> main() async {
   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   await Hive.initFlutter();
   Hive.registerAdapter(AddToCartAdapter());
   HiveBoxes.cartBox = await Hive.openBox<AddToCart>(Constants.cartBoxName);
   runApp(const MyApp());
 }
```

To make your code better, I suggest some stuffs like creating a class for constant names to prevent typos and creating some static variable to get access Hive Boxes easily like that:

```
class Constants{
    static const cartBoxName = 'CartBox';
}

class HiveBoxes{
   static late Box cartBox;
}
```

About your method you can do like that:

```
Future cartlist(String name, String unit, String qty, String price) async {
///we don't need to open box again, so please delete this commented code
//await Hive.openBox("addToCart");
final cart = AddToCart()
  ..name = name
  ..unit = unit
  ..qty = qty
  ..price = price;

HiveBoxes.cartBox.put("sampleKey", cart);;
// It's also wrong code: Box.add(cart);
}
```

Comment: `Unhandled Exception: HiveError: You need to initialize Hive or provide a path to store the box.` getting error

Comment: I have updated my question sir... I really did not understand where to put that *same path for openBox* method.

Comment: please update your answer with my new code sir.

Comment: Please, pay attention that HiveBoxes and Constants are your custom classes not library related.

Comment: Yes sir. now getting this error. `[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: LateInitializationError: Field 'cartBox' has not been initialized.`

Comment: That's because you are interacting this box before initializeng it. Are you sure that you are executing    HiveBoxes.cartBox = await Hive.openBox<AddToCart>(Constants.cartBoxName); in main function. Did you restarted flutter application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250108/discussion-between-jakhongir-anasov-and-swapnil-mane).

Comment: @swapnilmane could you fix your issue. If yes, please kindly accept the answer. If not, let me know what problem are you facing now?

Comment: now getting new error at startup...Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)

Comment: I have questioned here...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74684235/flutter-unhandled-exception-platformexceptionchannel-error-unable-to-establ

Comment: Why you created another question? It doesn't seem like common thing in stackoverflow community. I mean if the issue is resolved, you need to accept the answer. The error you are getting know may not be related at all with this question.

Comment: I accepted the answer,sir. but this time getting new error...

Comment: I saw the new question. I wondered why you are still using "final document = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();" I even sent you the code sample, which doesn't require specifying doucment.

Comment: I was using your code. but getting that platformexception error. SO i thought changing String to final may help to fix it but not worked. so,

Comment: If you want we can try to fix your issue with Telegram, Zoom or etc

Comment: Because it is getting big time to reach out as you are getting different errors and trying different things.

Comment: Sorry sir. I am not able to use zoom or telegram. Can't we fix it here sir ??

Comment: I just wanted to help with live coding, as it would take much less time. By the way I answered your new question. Let's continue there