# Flutter - Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null,

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-hive, path-provider

I am trying to use Hive database in my flutter project. In order to use hive db I will have to use path_provider package. I installed that too. but when I run the app again or restart it is neither running nor restarting and getting this error.

[image]

```
 Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)

E/flutter (15905): #0
PathProviderApi.getApplicationDocumentsPath
package:path_provider_android/messages.g.dart:9
```

**ANDROID MANIFEST FILE PERMISSIONS**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
   />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
  />
```

**MY CODE**

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final document = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory(); // ERROR AT THIS LINE
  Hive.init(document.path);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I didn't put any uses-permission in Maneifest file to use Hive. Instead of Hive.init(), I would like to suggest to use Hive.initFlutter(). But without

```
final document = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
```

inside initFlutter() method, these actions are already done by itself.

```
Future<void> main() async {
 WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
 Hive.initFlutter();
 runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Comment: No sir...getting same error.

Comment: I have added the error image sir.

Comment: Please, carefully do things in answers. I said without that line of code. But you din't delete it. I will update answer with code. Please edit the code exactly.

Comment: Sir. problem got solved. in fact we created a new project and moved the all code into project and it worked.

Comment: I am happy for you. So just to clarify did you change the code as I said or din’t?

Comment: Your code worked...When we create a new project we use the code provided by you. And i have accepted your answer too...There is a question can we ask for a permission in main() function in flutter??

Comment: Yes of course. You can ask for permission. But I think it is not a good idea. What kinda permission do you want to ask?

Comment: File handling permission or storage permission sir.

Comment: Hmm. Ok. It would be appropriate if you do this in according page instead of main function

Answer (score 1):

Adding permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` file is like defining all the permission you may use in your app. but to actually use those permissions, you need to ask user to allow those permissions like using internal/external storage. One way to do this is with [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) package.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to initialize your Flutter plugins first, including the path_provider. This can be done by calling GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register with a FlutterPluginRegistry as a parameter. Examples of FlutterPluginRegistry conforming classes are FlutterAppDelegate / FlutterViewController on iOS, as well as FlutterEngine.